# How to publish the spring actuator /health endpoint to a different port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

So I want to publish my `/health` spring actuator endpoint to port `9999` but at the same time I want the remaining actuator endpoints like `/metrics` to publish it to the `defaultmanagement.server.port`.
How to achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Can I override it just for this endpoint , something like enpoints.health.port = "9999" ?

Comment: Spring Boot by default offers the possibility to define different ports for application and management - server.port=8080; management.port=9999; management.port is for all actuator endpoints. You can define additional ports via server.additionalPorts=9999. You can use TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory to define redirects (e.g. redirect from 9999 to 8080). But what is the reason that you want to split the actuator endpoints between different ports?

Comment: Its just all the services are deployed in kubernetes and we want to all the services (no matter the framework) publish the healthcheck to port 9999 . Also sorry, I didn't follow your reply . I reckon changing the management port will make all the actuator endpoints publish to 9999 but I want just the health to publish to 9999 . Is it possible without using Tomcat redirect ?